# How long before RotS was season 6 of TCW?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

**spoilers for seasons 6 and 7 of The Clone Wars**

In season 6 of TCW, Fives tries to uncover the truth about the clones' inhibitor chips, ultimately dying in Rex's arms as he's killed.  In season 7, during the events of Order 66, Ahsoka seeks out the report Rex made about Fives' findings to learn about the chips.

This could have been mentioned somewhere and I missed it, but how much time takes place between these events?  Wookieepedia says that Fives died in 19 BBY.  This is the exact year that season 7 (and Revenge of the Sith) take place - so did Fives die only months before?  Do we have a more exact number?

Answer (score 3):

### The same year.

*Star Wars: Galactic Atlas* places both the final episode of season 5, *The Wrong Jedi*, and the unfinished but canon [Utapau](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_Death_on_Utapau) arc in 19 BBY. According to [an official series chronological order guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629215538/https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-the-clone-wars-chronological-episodeorder), all of season six takes place between that season five episode and the Utapau arc. That means that season six also takes place in 19BBY.

| Sequence | Episode | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | 520 | The Wrong Jedi |
| 109 | 601 | The Unknown |
| 110 | 602 | Conspiracy |
| 111 | 603 | Fugitive |
| 112 | 604 | Orders |
| 113 | 605 | An Old Friend |
| 114 | 606 | The Rise of Clovis |
| 115 | 607 | Crisis at the Heart |
| 116 | 608 | The Disappeared |
| 117 | 609 | The Disappeared: Pt. II |
| 118 | 610 | The Lost One |
| 119 | 611 | Voices |
| 120 | 612 | Destiny |
| 121 | 613 | Sacrifice |
|  |  | ***Crystal Crisis On Utapau* Story Reels** |
| 122 |  | A Death on Utapau |
| 123 |  | In Search of the Crystal |
| 124 |  | Crystal Crisis |
| 125 |  | The Big Bang |

The atlas also places *Revenge of the Sith* in 19BBY.

I'm sorry the answer isn't super specific, but it would appear to be all that we have at the moment. More speculatively, Ahsoka's arc with the Martez sisters seems to occur pretty shortly after her leaving the Jedi Order. I would then guess that the gap between season six and the film is a few months at most.

Answer (score 0):

**A few months, less than a year** is currently the only answer we have

I don't think it's been specified exactly in canon

Comment: While this is correct, it would be a better answer if you could at least reference a more canonical source than Wookieepedia to establish the timeline.

Comment: Like I said, in canon we have no idea.